# Working with interface and types on golang

Tags: go

I'm working on a generic implementation of a paginator for DB queries with GORM

```
type Cursor struct {
    Data []interface{}
    Next int
}

type Paginator struct {
    PageSize int
    Model    interface{}
}
```

The problem is, I don't know how to instantiate a new array to retrieve results from DB depending on the `Paginator.Model` type with this line

```
db.Model(paginator.Model).Limit(paginator.PageSize).Offset(page - 1).Find(&data)
```

How can I instantiate `data` to work with `Find`?

Answer (score -1):

Is your issue not knowing how to create a slice?

You can do:

```
var data []interface{}{} // make an empty slice of type interface{}
```

if you are trying to create a Custor struct, you can also do:

```
c := Cursor{Data: []interface{}{}}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/xnZBD2AazT)

Comment: No, that's not what i'm trying